# How can I make the mic mute key work in MS Teams with Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, microsoft-teams

Since for some reason the microphone mute key does not work in MS Teams, I wanted to solve this issue with the following assignment. I found out that the mute key is actually F14 using [event.keyCode tester](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/mPgoYJ) However, it does not work, and I don't know why.

```
F14::Send {Ctrl Shift M}
```

When I track the mic mute key with AutoHotkey, it says the following after pressing it (it generates 3 entries for this one special key):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!F14::Send ^+m
```

I used the AutoHotkey key history to find out, that not only F14 was pressed by this key, but also the (left) Windows and Alt key, so the statement above finally works, hurray! :)

Thanks also to Wenfang Du, he pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: If you want to make it work without the Teams window having to be active, have a look here https://tdalon.github.io/ahk/Teams-Global-Hotkeys

Answer (score 1):

Use the mute key to toggle mute:

```
Volume_Mute::SendInput ^+m
```

References:

- [Keyboard shortcuts for Microsoft Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-teams-2e8e2a70-e8d8-4a19-949b-4c36dd5292d2#bkmk_calling)
- [Multimedia Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#multimedia)
- [Send variants](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Send_variants)

Comment: Thank you, @Wenfang Du, however, I just saw that I made a mistake in my question. It is not the mute key I want to use, it is actually explicitely the microphone mute/toggle key!

Comment: @SimonFerndriger Unfortunately, I don't have a microphone at hand, but [this thread](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=15509) looks really promising, also check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/airstrike/5cb66c97a288efdb578a).

Comment: I think I found the problem. Currently, when I press my "mic mute" button on my keyboard, it actually triggers Win+Alt, as I found out with this tool: https://en.key-test.ru/ - this makes sense, as it underlines the first letters in the top menu of Windows applications when I press it. So, I guess I need to fix my HP USB Premium Keyboard keyboard, but how?

Comment: I added the AutoHotkey key history in my description. Maybe this helps to correctly address this special key?